Jetpack Compose Preview Warning Shown
i currently migrate some Fragments to Compose. When launching the Preview of a Composeable i get this warning screen.
compileSdk = 34

defaultConfig {
    minSdk = 26
    targetSdk = 34

Is there any Info out there about this ? Worked with compose before, never seen such warning.
The Compose version i use is "2023.10.01", is it because of not using a more modern version ?
Thx

